# How can i put app subdir classess under a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to namespace all my classes put in a `app/cms` folder under `Cms` module. So, let's say i have a following file:

```
# /app/cms/types/post.rb
class Cms::Types::Post
end
```

Rails assumes that class definition of a file put in this dir should be `Types::Post` instead of `Cms::Types::Post`. So, when calling `Cms::Types::Post.new`, rails throws

```
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Types::Post, expected /Users/xxx/workspace/personal/xxx/app/cms/types/post.rb to define it)
```

How can i namespace all these files under `Cms`?

I'm on rails 5.2.0

Comment: Why dont you put everything in another dir so your path would be like `/app/external_apps/cms/types/post.rb`?

Comment: i'm creating a rails engine and putting all these classes in /app/cms would be an official recommended way fo customizing my engine. I can't ask my users to put the code in the path you suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

What is `Post`? I mean, what is the nature of `Post`? For instance, is it a service?

If it were a service (for example), I would put it in:

```
/app/services/cms/types/post_service.rb
```

And then define it as:

```
class Cms::Types::PostService
end
```

If it were a `type` (which seems like it might be a problematic name), then I would define it in:

```
/app/types/cms/post_type.rb
```

and define it as:

```
class Cms::PostType
end
```

In other words, name the directory under `/app` using the description of what `Post` is (just like rails does with `models`, `controllers`, etc.) and then add the description (in the singular form) to the end of your definition (rails does this with `controllers`, `helpers`, and `mailers`, but not with `models`).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you use `namespace` you need to have your file structure as below:

```
module Cms
  module Types
    class Post
    end
  end
end
```

`EDIT:` Also to make it, autoload the path, you could add the below line in your `application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'cms').to_s
```

Comment: it still raises `LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Types::Post, expected /Users/xxx/workspace/personal/xxx/app/cms/types/post.rb to define it)` when calling `Cms::Types::Post.new`

Comment: `require_relative 'path_to_your_class'`

Comment: wouldn't it break autoloading / app in dev env ?